Does Hume respond to Cleanthe’s voice analogy in his book?
In Hume’s Dialogues Concerning Natural Religion, after Cleanthes offers an argument from analogy that shows likeness between the universe and other artifacts of design, Philo (a character in the book) says,

In this cautious proceeding of the astronomers, you may read your own condemnation, CLEANTHES; or rather may see, that the subject in which you are engaged exceeds all human reason and inquiry. Can you pretend to show any such similarity between the fabric of a house, and the generation of a universe? Have you ever seen nature in any such situation as resembles the first arrangement of the elements? Have worlds ever been formed under your eye; and have you had leisure to observe the whole progress of the phenomenon, from the first appearance of order to its final consummation? If you have, then cite your experience, and deliver your theory. (Part 2)

Philo essentially points out that for something like a house, that we know to be designed, we can observe the builder or builders often, along with the entire construction process of basic elements to a house. We do not have the same luxury with respect to the universe. Thus, something like a house and the universe are simply not similar.
In Part 3, Cleanthes states:

Suppose, therefore, that an articulate voice were heard in the clouds, much louder and more melodious than any which human art could ever reach: Suppose, that this voice were extended in the same instant over all nations, and spoke to each nation in its own language and dialect: Suppose, that the words delivered not only contain a just sense and meaning, but convey some instruction altogether worthy of a benevolent Being, superior to mankind: Could you possibly hesitate a moment concerning the cause of this voice? and must you not instantly ascribe it to some design or purpose? Yet I cannot see but all the same objections (if they merit that appellation) which lie against the system of Theism, may also be produced against this inference.


Might you not say, that all conclusions concerning fact were founded on experience: that when we hear an articulate voice in the dark, and thence infer a man, it is only the resemblance of the effects which leads us to conclude that there is a like resemblance in the cause: but that this extraordinary voice, by its loudness, extent, and flexibility to all languages, bears so little analogy to any human voice, that we have no reason to suppose any analogy in their causes: and consequently, that a rational, wise, coherent speech proceeded, you know not whence, from some accidental whistling of the winds, not from any divine reason or intelligence? You see clearly your own objections in these cavils, and I hope too you see clearly, that they cannot possibly have more force in the one case than in the other.

He gives the analogy of comprehensible speech coming from the sky and states that most of us would infer design in this case even though we don’t have the same luxury of how this voice comes about the way we do for a house. This then serves as a response to Philo’s objections.
After this, the topic of the conversation between these characters seems to digress and Philo does not seem to have a direct response to this.
Does Hume, through the invented character Philo, or through any other work, have a direct response to this? If not, what could a possible response look like?

"If not, what could a possible response look like?" That's an opinion-based question that does not fit this site.

Hm, read the book and find out?

I don't know about Hume's response, but this is a possible response.


"The universe and known-designed things aren't at all similar"
"But what if we had something that is similar?"
"Well, then you'd have better evidence than the actual evidence you've got!"


Let's consider hearing a voice regularly:

Do we need to see the speaker, and see them moving their mouth, to reasonably conclude that it's a person's voice? I'd firmly say no.
Can we differentiate voices from non-voices, based on sound alone, without seeing what generates the sound? I'd say yes, and in fact we can generally do a lot better than this, by being able to more specifically identify what caused the sound with a reasonable idea where that thing is. Of course, this isn't perfect, some people can emulate the sounds of other things (although they do so intentionally) and machines can reproduce the sound of voice (although they were intentionally designed to reproduce sounds, often specifically voices).

And just to avoid focusing too narrowly on sounds and to bring it back to the original analogy:

Do we need to see a particular house having been built, to reasonably conclude that it was built? I'd again firmly say no.
Can we differentiate houses from non-houses, without seeing who built each house? I'd say yes.

We obviously need to see some speakers and house builders at some point, to know that voices have speakers and houses have builders.
But after establishing that baseline, the way we identify voices and houses and designed things is from it having similar properties as other voices and houses and designed things (and no, that doesn't include "complexity", at least not directly). For example, we might look for particular patterns and shapes that appear more frequently in designed things than in nature.
But this also raises an issue: if one proposes that nature itself is designed, then there is nothing to differentiate designed things from, so we wouldn't be able to identify design in the first place. I suppose one might differentiate direct design from indirect design (e.g. God popping things into existence in a certain state versus God setting processes in motion). But many or most things designed in the modern day are indirect, in that we use machines that create our products of design for us. And still we can identify such design as being very different from nature.
This closely resembles the debate around the teleological argument (argument from design) and its criticisms.

bears so little analogy to any human voice ... a rational, wise, coherent speech

That sounds like a lot of similarity presented in that very same sentence.
This argument is in conflict with itself: It needs to be similar enough to human voices that we can identify it as a voice and identify what it is saying. But it also needs to be different enough so that we can't reasonably conclude that it's a voice.
I haven't heard "accidental whistling of the winds" producing anything remotely mistakable for a human voice. And in cases where it does, it's probably unintelligible and/or barely more than a syllable. It doesn't seem hugely plausible, although there may be more plausible alternatives, like some global coordinated effort by intelligent speaking beings that are known to exist (humans). Or aliens. Probably still implausible, but it could measure up favourably against some proposed being that exists outside of space and time or whatever. Although there are versions of this that may make those other explanations less plausible, like e.g. the message being beamed straight into each person's head, possibly including some things only meaningful to that person.

Thank you for your thoughts. It is unfortunate that so much of analogical arguments relies upon the vague notions of likeness and similarity. Part XII of his book is full of qualms against this concept

No, these "Dialogues Concerning Natural Religion" were published after Humes death only, Hume rightfully deemed it dangerous for his reputation to publish such thoughts during his lifetime during a time where doubting religion could end careers.
(This is similar to Darwin not publishing his "On the Origin of Species" for roughly 20 years.)
Hume had already suffered various other setbacks and threats in his career due to his published skeptical views on religion.
So Hume did not dare to expose himself more directly to attacks by publishing this work, and did thus not write more about it. The absence of a response by the character "Philo" in the Dialogues (usually regarded as representing Humes own opinions) may be seen as further cautious step Hume took in case the manuscript were leaked in his lifetime.

The book is chock full of criticisms against all kinds of various arguments for god. And if the book was published after his death, why would an additional response for a very specific point make a difference in terms of his danger?

That's why I said "may be seen".
